# How can I make std::make_pair usable with std::bind*?

Tags: c++, templates

I'd like to use [`std::make_pair`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/utility/make_pair/) usable with e.g. [`std::bind2nd`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/functional/bind2nd/) so that I get an unary function object which I could use with e.g. [`std::transform`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/transform/).

Right now I'm using

```
template <typename T, typename U>
struct pair_creator : std::binary_function<T, U, std::pair<T, U> >
{
    std::pair<T, U> operator()( T arg1, U arg2 ) const {
        return std::make_pair( arg1, arg2 );
    }
};

// ...

std::transform( start1, end2, start2, std::bind2nd( pair_creator<int, bool>(), true ) );
```

but I wonder - is there an easier way to make `std::make_pair` (or potentially any other binary function) usable with the binders except by writing little wrapper classes like `pair_creator` by hand?

I'd need a C++03 solution (for some obscure reason, stackoverflow always rewrites my [c++0x](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b0x) tag to [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) when saving the post...).

Comment: C++0x was the working name for C++11 until it was completed a few months ago.

Comment: @Mike: Ah, makes sense. I somehow thought the `c++0x` tag should also match my C++03 question :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need `std::ptr_fun`, which turns a plain function pointer into an adaptable binary function object (or a unary function object, if you pass it a one-arg function):

```
#include <functional>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> intvec;
    intvec.push_back(0);
    intvec.push_back(1);
    std::vector<std::pair<int,bool> > pairvec(intvec.size());
    std::transform(
        intvec.begin(),
        intvec.end(),
        pairvec.begin(),
        // this is the significant line
        std::bind2nd(std::ptr_fun(std::make_pair<int, bool>), true)
    );
    std::cout << pairvec[1].first << " " << pairvec[1].second << "\n";
}
```

`ptr_fun` is declared:

```
template <class Arg1, class Arg2, class Result>
pointer_to_binary_function<Arg1,Arg2,Result>
ptr_fun(Result (*)(Arg1,Arg2));
```

And for the unary version:

```
template <class Arg, class Result>
pointer_to_unary_function<Arg,Result>
ptr_fun(Result (*)(Arg));
```

Comment: Are you sure that's legit in C++11? There was some issue with specifying explicit template arguments for `make_pair` (e.g. [see here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vclanguage/thread/bab04536-8a8d-4b5e-9a49-e10144688667#b840d54d-d4e9-4602-9273-4118addb8041) and [here](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/465859/make-pair-generates-c2264) and [here](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/691756/std-make-pair-error-in-vc11))...

Comment: @Kerrek: questioner asked for a C++03 solution, so no I am not sure :-). I suppose for C++11 you could use a wrapper `template <typename T, typename U> std::pair<T,U> backward_compatible_make_pair(T t, U u) return std::make_pair(t,u); }`, or something of the sort. I think that should behave like the old C++03 `make_pair`. Hence it will copy the argument, even in cases where the C++11 `make_pair` would move it.

Comment: +1 Ah, perfect. I'll accept this answer soon in case nobody comes up with a nicer discussion of `std::ptr_fun`, which is apparently exactly what I want.

Answer (score -1):

Use lambda don't need to use bind adaptor.

```
    std::vector<int> start1 = list_of(1)(2)(3)(4)(5);
    std::vector<int> start2 = list_of(10)(20)(30)(40)(50);
    std::vector<Pair> w_vecofpair; // vector of pair
    w_vofpair.reserve(start1.size()); 
    // create pair using lambda
    std::transform( std::begin(start1), std::end(start1), std::begin(start2), // ranges 
        std::back_inserter(w_vecofpair),  // result 
        [](int a,int b) { return std::make_pair(a,b);}); // pair creator

    for (auto& pairInt : w_vecofpair)
    {
        std::cout << pairInt << "\n"; 
    }

    // bind 2nd arg to some value, say 2
    std::transform( std::begin(start1), std::end(start1), std::begin(start2), 
        std::back_inserter(w_vecofpair), [](int a, int b) { return std::make_pair(a,2);});

    for (auto& second : w_vecofpair | map_values)
    {
        std::cout << "The second value of our bind 2nd is: " << second << "\n";
        assert(second==2);
    }
```

Comment: Lambda functions are not available in C++03 (requested by the OP) though.